# How to clear npm cache errors in npm package module?

Tags: angular, npm

Actually I am creating an Angular application and I had encountered these errors while working:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"karma-qunit":"*","k'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yuvan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-02T14_06_06_337Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Should be nice to view your package.json! I guess that there is your problem.

Comment: which commands have you typed to get these errors?

Comment: ng new angular-app

Comment: I got this error running 'npm install"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the command of npm to clear these errors i had found that yesterday and it was pretty simple to use :

**npm cache clean --force**